# Why doesn't FormFunction work?

Tags: form-building

I'm trying to understand and use FormFunction.  I go to the local documentation on my system and this is what it shows:

[image]

I execute the commands for the definition of form and execute form[].  This is what I get:

[image]

What do I do to get FormFunction to work? I've tried defining f by setting

```
f[x_]:=x
```

first. But it doesn't help.

Comment: Do you have `TraditionalForm` formatting on? `FormFunction` will only work with `StandardForm`.

Comment: I do have that as the default output in my own stylesheets but not on the documentation.  When I wrapped the command inside StandardForm[ ] I got it to work.  Thanks for letting me know this.  I don't see this fact in the documentation.

Comment: Most programming functionality is built to work with `StandardForm`, so it makes sense. `Format` can take a second argument to specify the format (`StandardForm` or `TraditionalForm`), and clearly that's what they did here.